# Unable to transfer Bitcoin to USD

Tags: bitpay

I have Bitcoins in my Bitpay wallet that I need to cash out. I earlier assumed that a Bitpay wallet would have a linked Online Bitpay account. I gave my BitPay Wallet Address to a client who transferred bitcoins to my wallet. Bitpay Support says that they do not see any Bitcoins on my Online acc. How does this work? Bitpay is not clear about what they want me to do. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no link between a BitPay business account and a BitPay wallet. If you gave an individual a receiving address belonging to your wallet, then you should see the bitcoin arrive directly to your wallet.

If you were trying to have those funds routed through your business account, you should send your client a bill using the Email Bill tool or add a payment button on your website.  They can generate an invoice from the bill or payment button and when they pay the invoice, the funds are deposited to your BitPay business ledger and then settled through the settlement process.

If you need more information, please contact BitPay via the support form at https://help.bitpay.com/requestHelp.  There is also a lot of information about setting up your business to accept bitcoin as a payment option at the following link: https://bitpay.com/docs.